# OSError when importing XGBoost

Tags: python, xgboost

I have installed XGBoost using sudo pip install. When I attempt to lmport I receive an OSError library not loaded, image not found. I have installed Xcode and my compiler is clack. When I enter clack at the command line I receive another error: no input files possibly suggesting $PATH may need to be modified. How can $PATH be modified and will this allow XGBoost to be loaded properly?

Answer (score 1):

The error saying no input files means you haven't given it any input files to compile. This is an expected error which even gcc, clang, etc. give. So, I do not think this is the correct debug step for your problem.

#### With pypi

When installing xgboost using pip on OSX, I receive an error saying `clang-omp++` was not found. And eventually gives an error `__builtin__.XGBoostLibraryNotFound: Cannot find XGBoost Libarary in the candicate path, did you install compilers and run build.sh in root path?`. So, it has some bug and can't be installed it seems.

And this seems to be a known issue: https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/1446#issuecomment-239655078

#### Working method

This is how I got xgboost to be installed:

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost.git
cd xgboost
cp make/minimum.mk config.mk
make -j
```

This works using the builtin clang compiler as well as gcc from brew. For more info read https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build.html#building-on-osx

Now to install the python package:

```
cd python-package
python setup.py install
```

Read more at https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build.html#python-package-installation . Note that the `python setup.py install` may need sudo if you aren't using a virtualenv.

Comment: The installation of XGBoost in a virtual environment was successful; however my attempt to enable multithreading via Open MP has been problematic. I have not been able to install gfortran despite downloading the appropriate binaries for Mac OS Sierra.

Comment: I have not tried openmp enabled xgboost in Sierra either. Have you tried installing `brew install gcc --without-multilib`  as the docs state ?

Comment: I don't have home brew installed as a package manager. I have macports but there is no port for gfortran. Does macports have to be uninstalled and brew installed?

Comment: I have not used macports personally ... so I am not sure. I think if you want more help regarding that a new question should attract the appropriate people. I can only help you to find something already on google like http://mathcancer.blogspot.in/2016/01/PrepOSXForCoding-MacPorts.html regarding macports and installing gcc+openmp in Mac. Not my area of expertise